# Wrap Image with div on hover using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have to make a window whenever I hover over any image. The constraint is the window is defined and should not be repeated. Means, if I have 10 images, instead of 10 similar windows, only 1 window should dynamically change its width height and position (left, right, top, bottom) to act as a border for the image. The border effect can be obtained using CSS but I have other requirements for which I need this dynamic border effect.

```
<div>  <!-- This is the border div -->
   <div id="top" class="imageBorder" style="display: block; width: 105px">Top</div>
   <div id="left" class="imageBorder" style="display: block; width: 105px"></div>
   <div id="right" class="imageBorder" style="display: block; width: 105px"></div>
   <div id="bottom" class="imageBorder" style="display: block; width: 105px">Bottom</div>
</div>
```

This above div is used as the window. Whenever I hover on any image, this div should surround it. I don't want this div to be copied and associated to each image at a time.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2fmo1xjm/)

[image]

Comment: That window div has 4 divs within it. The `#top` and `#bottom` have all 4 borders, but the `#left` and `#right` only have one border, why is that? What code do you have that fails to create a **dynamic** frame? All I see is HTML and some inert CSS.

Comment: Where do you want the image inside the div? This is essentially a container. Nothing a little jQuery can't handle. Add a class to the images and use an event listener and use `this` to attach to div container. Why not just define the container and remove the innerHtml elements? The inner elements are all the same so remove them IMHO

Comment: So you want a window on the hovered image? Or do you want the hovered image to appear in the window (at the very bottom)?

Comment: @zer00ne Thats cause later I will be adding background color, effect will be like a thick border. But since #left has only one side border, so it will form a black border only on left side. Hope its clear.

Comment: @yardpenalty The images will be different. The border div will lay adjacent to the image border. Image should not be inside the border div. If you think of adding classes, you can do. The objective is that this single div should show when hover on any image.

Comment: @A.Lau So you want a window on the hovered image(any image hovered)? --> `Yes`

Comment: Ok so when you hover over the image you want that div container to show up? So what you can do is use mouseover event listener and based on position of the image you can move container relative to image position and make zIndex of image $(this) two more than the page and make the container one more than the page.

Comment: @yardpenalty Thanks for your help. It will be very grateful, if you can edit my jsfiddle. I am not clear on positioning the border divs wrt image position. I tried e.pageX, e.pageY, but for the entire image the x and y value will differ  as image is a matrix of coordinates. so will the border div will vary for each pixel coordinate.

Comment: I am working on one right now will post in a few minutes.

Comment: @yardpenalty Thanks. Appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the images are not thumbnails and they are different sizes then you can make a single container's width and height dynamic based on the selected/active image's width and height.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container"></div>

<img class="img" src="http://www.so.com/390px-Amtgard-300x200.jpg" />
<img class="img" src="http://www.so.com/390px-Amtgard-300x200.jpg" />
<img class="img" src="http://www.so.com/390px-Amtgard-300x200.jpg" />
```

**CSS**

```
 #container{
  position: absolute; 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red; 
  z-index: 2; 
  display:none;
 }
.img{max-width: 80px; max-height: 80px; z-index: 10000;}
```

**JS/jQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".img").hover(function(){
       //on mouseenter
       var img = $(this);
       img.addClass("this");
       var c =  $("#container");   
       //change container width/height based on image size
       c.css({width:img.outerWidth() + 20, height:  img.outerHeight + 10});
      //position container
      c.css({top:img.offset().top - 10, left:  img.offset().left - 10,   position:'absolute'}).fadeIn("fast");
      //reset other images z-index
      $(".img:not(.this)").css("zIndex","1");
   }, function(){
  //on mouseleave
  if(!$("#container").css("display","none"))
      $("#container").fadeOut("fast");             
      $(".img").css("zIndex","4");                 
      $(this).removeClass("this");
});
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/61kovu51/10/)

**Explanation**

jQuery is the most powerful javascript library out there, I suggest you learn how to use this exclusively as it will sharpen your javascript skills and improve your UI skills as well. Typically I define my html elements using classes and ids so I can take advantage of javascript/jQuery.

**.hover**

I am using the `.hover` event handler which is explained in detail [here](https://api.jquery.com/hover/). Using this event handler you can define the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` using a single handler as the first anonymous function handles the `mouseenter` while the second handles the `mouseleave`.

**.css**

This jQuery method allows you to do practially anything you want to your html's css on the fly.

**NOTE:** outerWidth(), outerHeight() or width(), height() will have different results. Using which one depends on whether or not the element has `box-sizing:border-box` or `border`.

**.css("zIndex", "4")**

This is jQuery's way of editing css `z-index` on the fly. This is how the `#container` is able to overlap the other images not active.

**$(this)**

When you use an event handler (I suggest you learn  how to use as many as possible) with a css class the `$(this)` becomes invaluable. This allows you to isolate the element from the class inside the event handler.

**.addClass("this")**

The `addClass()` and `removeClass()` is how you can improve the user experience.
I use this alot with `hidden` and `disabled` where I need to disable buttons or hide them etc.

**.not("this)**

This is a quick and easy way to isolate the element for longer than the event handler is in scope. I use this alot in dropdown lists aka select lists.

**fadeIn('slow'), fadeOut('fast')**

Use this jQuery method with any html element that has the property: `display: none`. It allows you to toggle whether or not the element is visible which is an upgrade over toggling between `display: none - block or inline`

**In closing**

The one thing you must familiarize yourself with when it comes to event handling and that is propagation! When dealing with event handling the event listeners will listen for an event based on the following:

A: the type of event 
ie: on('click'), on('submit'), on('mouseenter'), on('change') etc...

and

B: the type of element
ie: class, or html element (ie: div, input, select, a, button etc...)

This can cause erroneous results especially if the elements are created dynamically.

Get familiar with event propagation, event bubbling and event closures!

Comment: The red border needs to be above the other images. Thanks

Comment: I got it now. Do you need the container to be dynamic in size?

Comment: In my case, I will keep the image size constant. So, box size can be same.

Comment: I just added everything you need then. Real clean. Please see update.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Can you please give some explanation. Comment beside lines is also ok. I am new to JS.

Answer (score 1):

I used jquery's `.hover()`, `.before()` and `.after`()

https://jsfiddle.net/2fmo1xjm/3/

```
$("div > img").hover( function()
{
    $(this).before( `<div id='main_window'><div id="top" class="imageBorder" style="display: block; width: 105px">Top</div>
<div id="left" class="imageBorder" style="display: block; width: 105px"></div>` );
    $(this).after(`<div id="right" class="imageBorder" style="display: block; width: 105px"></div>
<div id="bottom" class="imageBorder" style="display: block; width: 105px">Bottom</div>
</div>`);
},
function()
{
    $("#top, #left, #bottom, #right").remove();
});
```

play around with it to get the window you want, and of course make it nicer.

**Updated:**

Use `.wrap()` instead. Has top and bottom headers if you need.

https://jsfiddle.net/2fmo1xjm/9/

Comment: nice hack. kudos. Whenever the border div is show on hover, can it overlap over neighbor img instead of expanding. @A. Lau

Comment: Why is .before() and .after() used.

Comment: `.before()` is used to insert before the img. `.after()` is used to insert after it. If you want to do something like overlapping, `.replaceWith()` and `replaceAll()` might suit you better

Comment: Actually you might want to use `.wrap()`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about final look and behavior of border div (you can tweak it to fit your needs), but this should help. I made few changes in CSS, to make all works...

```js
$( "img" ).hover(
  function() {
  $('.border-div').css('display','block');
    
     $('.border-div').css('width',$(this).width()+5+'px');
     $('.border-div').css('height',$(this).height()+5+'px');

      $('.border-div').css('left',$(this).offset().left-1.2+'px');
     $('.border-div').css('top',$(this).offset().top-2+'px');
     
  },
  function() {
    $('.border-div').css('display','none');
  }
);
```

```css
.imageStyle{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  cursor:pointer;
}

#top{
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;        
 border-top: 1px solid #333333;        
 border-right: 1px solid #333333;        
 border-left: 1px solid #333333;        

}

#left{
  border-left: 1px solid #333333;        
 width: 5px; 
}

#right { 
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;        
  width: 5px;   
} 

#bottom {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;        
 border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;        
 border-right: 1px solid #333333;        
 border-left: 1px solid #333333; 
position:absolute;
width:100%;
bottom:0px;

}

img {
  display:block;
  z-index:9;
  position:relative;
}
.border-div {
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zasBPCmkmm4/V4S6jz0bOeI/AAAAAAAAHAI/qq7mYlCBjvsE4NWKWxyYi3IV9qHfpXgVwCLcB/s1600/seamlessly-repeating-background-with-abstract-composition.jpg" class="imageStyle">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zasBPCmkmm4/V4S6jz0bOeI/AAAAAAAAHAI/qq7mYlCBjvsE4NWKWxyYi3IV9qHfpXgVwCLcB/s1600/seamlessly-repeating-background-with-abstract-composition.jpg" class="imageStyle">
</div> 
<div>
  <img src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zasBPCmkmm4/V4S6jz0bOeI/AAAAAAAAHAI/qq7mYlCBjvsE4NWKWxyYi3IV9qHfpXgVwCLcB/s1600/seamlessly-repeating-background-with-abstract-composition.jpg" class="imageStyle">
</div> 
<div>
  <img src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zasBPCmkmm4/V4S6jz0bOeI/AAAAAAAAHAI/qq7mYlCBjvsE4NWKWxyYi3IV9qHfpXgVwCLcB/s1600/seamlessly-repeating-background-with-abstract-composition.jpg" class="imageStyle">
</div> 

<div class="border-div">  <!-- This is the border div -->
<div id="top" class="imageBorder" style="display: block;">Top</div>
<div id="left" class="imageBorder" style="display: block; "></div>
<div id="right" class="imageBorder" style="display: block; "></div>
<div id="bottom" class="imageBorder" style="display: block;">Bottom</div>
</div>
```

Important: to avoid problems on hover, border div is placed under the image...otherwise, there could be some blinking (when image and border div overlapping occurs).